# Open java Applet or Frame inside a parent Applet method and wait for input

Tags: java, swing, applet, awt

I have a Java applet (lets call it `parentApplet`) with a public method which must return information regarding the status of the performed actions (let's call it `getUserInput()`) . This method opens another Applet which needs user button input, by adding it as a child with `add(childApplet)`, and afterwards adding itself (the parent) as an **ActionListner** of the buttons in the `childApplet`, being able to run other methods when the user clicks on the buttons in the `childApplet`.

My question is, how can I halt `getUserInput()` execution until the user has clicked the `childApplet` buttons?

I tried to have a static variable that tracks the return information, and spinning on a  `while(var == null) Thread.Sleep(1000);` but it blocks the main thread, as it should.

PS: Having the childApplet as an applet can be changed to anything that could better fulfil the requirement of opening another panel on top of the parent applet.

### Details on `getUserInput()`

That `childApplet` has a canvas (a `Graphics` object from a `BufferedImage`) on which the user can draw and OK/Clear/Cancel buttons. When the user presses OK, I need to get the `BufferedImage` drawn. Do you know if this can be accomplished by extending a `JDialog`?

Comment: Use a `JOptionPane.showInputDialog(..)`

Comment: By input I didn't mean to get Strings from the user, refer to [this reply](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21193985/open-java-applet-or-frame-inside-a-parent-applet-method-and-wait-for-input/21199389?iemail=1&noredirect=1#comment31930025_21199389) for more info please.

Comment: That is relevant information that *should have been include in the question.*  :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need to restructure your app.  You can't do it the way you want.
Try creating a JDialog set it up as you like with input fields and an OK/Cancel button.
Then to show the dialog do:

```
  MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog(null, true);  //true = modal
  //dialog.setModalityType(ModalityType.DOCUMENT_MODAL);  //or specify modal here
  dialog.setVisible(true);  //waits until dialog is closed
  if (dialog.wasAccepted()) {
    //grab values from dialog
    dialog.getCanvas();
  }
```

In the dialog you would have:

```
  private boolean accepted = false;
  public boolean wasAccepted() {return accepted;}
  public Canvas getCanvas() {return canvas;}
  public ? getWhateverElseYouWant() {return ...;}
```

The OK button would:

```
accepted=true;
dispose();
```

The Cancel button would:

```
accepted=false;
dispose();
```

The JDialog will pump events while it's visible. So the setVisible() function will halt execution until the dialog is closed.

That should work better, and then you can return many user input fields.
You can even change the JDialog constructor to pass default value(s) in.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer! I'm sorry for not explaining better what `getUserInput()` would do but, by input I didn't mean it should get a string or something like that. That childApplet has a canvas (a `Graphics` object from a `BufferedImage`) on which the user can draw and ok/clear/cancel buttons. When the user presses OK, I need to get the `BufferedImage` drawn. Do you know if this can be accomplished by extending a JDialog?

Comment: Yes, you can do anything with JDialog.  Put a canvas in your dialog and add a function called getCanvas() in your dialog class.  I've edited the code above.

Comment: I'm accepting this as it was the first answer to my specific problem, that being said, refer to [Andrew Thompson answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21209812/859738) for some additional info on this subject.

Comment: I've successfully tested this, it has only one thing missing, if (like my case) you need the Dialog to block the application, you need to change its Modality. Using `dialog.setModalityType(ModalityType);`, I've come to the following results:

* ModalityType.MODELESS: Doesn't block the method execution neither the UI;
* ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL : Blocks the method execution and the parent UI;
* ModalityType.DOCUMENT_MODAL: Blocks the method execution but doesn't block the parent UI;

I've edited your answer to add this.

Comment: You can specify a modal dialog in the constructor arguments.  I normally do that anyways, I'll edit the code.

Answer (score 1):

> That `childApplet` has a canvas (a `Graphics` object from a `BufferedImage`) on which the user can draw and ok/clear/cancel buttons. When the user presses OK, I need to get the `BufferedImage` drawn.

First of all, it should not be an applet but a `JPanel` (it is not impossible to do it as an applet, but also not trivial).  Then you can show the `JPanel` in a one of three ways.

1. `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(..)`.  The idea would be to use the ready made OK/Cancel buttons of the option pane to tell the main app. whether to actually use image drawn.  I (as a user) would tend to expect the Clear button to not be in the group of buttons that dismisses the dialog.  Put that button in the panel you pass to the option pane.
2. A modal `JDialog`.  Creating a dialog is more work than using an option pane, but also more versatile.  For instance, if the panel you put into the dialog has a 'set size of drawing' option, it is easier to resize a dialog than an option pane.
3. Another card of a `CardLayout`.  The two previous suggestions have the dis/advantage that they will block the app. **and the browser** until dismissed.  This is good in that you can simply query the state of the drawing immediately after it is shown, confident that the user has finished drawing.  But it is bad in that the user might have the dialog or option pane sitting on screen for 30 minutes, and the rest of the browser will be inaccessible to them in that time.  By instead flipping to a card that shows the drawing panel, the browser is not blocked, and the app. can query the state of the drawing as soon as the user makes one of the OK/Cancel selections.

Comment: I'm accepting **Peter Quiring** answer as it was the first answer with the information I need to solve my specific problem, but, to be fair, your answer has extremely useful info and I think it should be somehow added in/merged/linked with the answer as well.

Comment: As of Java SE 6, you can set the `ModalityType` of a JDialog, which lets you control if the Dialog blocks the parent code execution and UI. [Refer this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21193985/open-java-applet-or-frame-inside-a-parent-applet-method-and-wait-for-input/21199389#comment31981758_21199389) for more info